# Showing $1+e^{-j\theta} =2e^{-j\theta/2}*\cos{\frac{\theta}2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

Show that $$1+e^{-j\theta} =2e^{-j\theta/2}*\cos{\frac{\theta}2}$$

I know of the Euler equation: $e^{j\theta}=\cos(\theta)+j\sin(\theta)$ but am unsure how to simply show that the above are equal.

Comment: Use Euler equation for $e^{j\theta/2}$ and $e^{-j\theta/2}$.

Comment: Write $1+e^{-j\theta} = e^{-j\theta/2}(e^{j\theta/2} + e^{-j\theta/2})$.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you!! That's the one

Comment: I added the "complex numbers" and "complex analysis" tags to your question, since they more directly describe the subject matter at hand.   I left the "differential equations" tag intact, since I suppose your identity is in some sense or other relevant to differential equations.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis Thank you for making this change for me! :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2\cos \dfrac{\theta}{2} = e^{i\theta/ 2} + e^{-i\theta / 2}; \tag{1}$

thus

$2e^{-i\theta / 2} \cos \dfrac{\theta}{2}$
$=e^{-i\theta / 2}(e^{i\theta/ 2} + e^{-i\theta / 2}) = 1 + e^{-i\theta}. \tag{2}$

Comment: My solution was not nearly as elegant, Thank you.

Comment: Thank you!  And thanks for the "acceptance"!  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use this equality

$$e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}=2\cos(\theta)$$